# Bootstrap-Table custom filteralgorithm

Tags: bootstrap-table

I'm trying to use Bootstrap-Table to show my data and I want to filter rows that a specified cell is empty and I don't want them to show up.

```
$('#tableId').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
    filterOptions: {
        filterAlgorithm: "not"
    }
});

$('#@tableId').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {"specifiedCell":""});
```

Sadly filterAlgorithm does not support `not` at code above.

What should I write in front of filterAlgorithm to use a custom filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see any good explanation about it in internet but by testing I understand that custom filter template is like this:

```
$('#tableId').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
    filterOptions: {
        filterAlgorithm: function (row, filter) {
            if(row['specifiedCell'] != filter['specifiedCell']){ //check row or row[cell] condition by `filter`
                return true;//it will the `row` will display.
            } else {
                return false;//it wont show the `row`
            }
        }
    }
});

$('#@ViewBag.dynamicData["tableId"]').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {
    "specifiedCell":""
});
```

In the code above I checked specified cell in the row with filter that contains values that shouldn't be on the table so by returning true on not being in filter I made custom `not` filter.